# How can I use XSLT to convert XSLT source files into Freemarker source files

Tags: xslt, freemarker

I am working in a project where there is a requirement to convert pre-written xsl files(250-300 lines) to equivalent freemarker template by writing equivalent tags : like this,

```
<sometag>
<xsl:value-of select="something">
</sometag>
```

Into

```
<sometag>
${something}
</sometag>
```

The XSLT file also contains `xsl:if`, `xsl:for-each`, `xsl:choose` etc.

Previously , I used to do it manually and it took a lot of effort for only a few templates, but now we have got around 65-70 templates. Converting these many templates is not at all feasible if done by hand.

How should I go about converting the XSLT into another format? Can I use XSLT to do the job?

Comment: I've never heard of freemarker but sounds like you could write XSLT to do this.

Comment: You are asking for recommendations about a tool which is not the purpose of Stack. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

You ask this question tagged as XSLT, so I take it not as a request for "which tool is best", but for a request as "how should I accomplish this task using XSLT".

In XSLT, you can process XSLT, as XSLT itself is XML anyway. So, make your XSLT the input file and write your XSLT the way you are used to. For instance, the example you give could be written as:

```
<xsl:template match="xsl:value-of">
    <xsl:text>${</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="@select"/>
    <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

Since it sounds that you are going to run this as a one-off effort, you should choose for XSLT 2.0 or 3.0, to save you the trouble of going over the limitations of XSLT 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Freemarker, IIRC, is one of those languages that uses angle brackets but isn't quite XML. The tricky thing in generating output in such a language using XSLT is to decide whether to generate XML output and then tweak the serialization (e.g. by using disable-output-escaping or character maps), or to generate text output (in which case you can't use XSLT constructs that produce element and attribute nodes as their output).

Because the amount of code is fairly small here (I once got involved with a project that had 250K lines of XSLT and a similar amount of Freemarker code) another of your options is to do the bulk of the conversion using XSLT and then "hand-tune" it by manual post-processing.

I'd love to have a discussion about why you are using Freemarker in preference to XSLT, but I'll resist the temptation...